# VbaProject.OTM does not work unless VB Editor opened once

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba

I'm looking for a solution to my issue which is when I copy my VbaProject.OTM and open Outlook my macro's don't run. All I have to do is open the VB editor and then close it/close outlook and start it and it works, but this is not ideal obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to sign the project with a self created code signing cert and add it to the "Trusted Publishers" store.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that your VbaProject.otm file is corrupted, please try renaming the VBAProject and making a fresh one.

1. Close Outlook client.
2. Locate your VbaProject.otm file.(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook. Remember to show hidden folder)
3. Rename the file or just delete it.
4. Restart your Outlook then a new VbaProject.otm file will be created.

For your reference: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4951c898-2102-4e1e-bc82-132d23a102c5/outlook-365-crashes-when-saving-vbaprojectotm?forum=outlook

Comment: Tried that many times, I will update OP